# SqlServerCe reference added to config after using NuGet

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce, nuget

Whenever I use NuGet in my VS 2013 solution, it seems to add the following to various config files in my projects:

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.242.0" newVersion="9.0.242.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This is causing problems for other devs who use the same source code. How can I make this stop? I've uninstalled all references to SqlServerCe that I can find in Add/Remove Programs and that hasn't helped.

Comment: You have a reference to an old SqlServerCe version somewhere in your solution.

Comment: Perhaps, but then wouldn't everybody who uses the solution experience the same? I'm the only one.

Comment: Are the other devs adding Nuget packages to the solution?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know.